# Rails script to find records where two columns match with any other record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find all invitations where the inviter_id and the invitee_id matches any other invitation.

But for the sake of generalizing the question, it might be better if I discuss the issue in terms of finding users whose first_name and last_name matches with any other user.

This script is working well in my development environment, but not in production because there are too many records.

```
matches = []

User.all.each_with_index do |user1, index|
    start = index + 1
    User.all[start..-1].each do |user2|
        if ((user1.first_name == user2.first_name) && (user1.last_name == user2.last_name)
            matches << user2
        end
    end
end
```

Any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of search is never going to be performant at scale. If it's something that you need regularly as part of your business logic, I would suggest caching references to duplicate users inside of the users table at the time that a user is created/destroyed/updated.

If it's just a script that you run occasionally, there is some performance improvement possible:

```rb
matches = []

User.all.each do |user|
  duplicates = User.where(first_name: user.first_name, last_name: user.last_name).where.not(id: user.id)
  (matches += duplicates.to_a) unless duplicates.empty?
end
```

EDIT: OMG I just discovered a blazing fast way to do this!

```rb
User.all.
     group_by{|u| u.first_name+u.last_name}.
     values.
     select{|users| users.length > 1}
```

As before, optimize by only selecting the fields you are interested in.

Comment: Aha!  I feel silly for not thinking of this.  I eliminated the cases of users being included in the match array multiple times by adding matchids = matches.pluck(:id) as the first line in the block.  Then I added .where.not(id: matchids) at the end of the 'where' query.

Comment: @JeffZivkovic I think you can improve the performance of the additions you describe in your comment by using `matches.uniq` outside the block

Comment: @JeffZivkovic also... don't forget to set up the appropriate indexes on the users table to make the `User.where...` statement as performant as possible.

Comment: @JeffZivkovic and finally (!!) there may be a small performance improvement by only selecting the fields of interest, so `User.select(:first_name, :last_name, :id, :account_number).where...`

Comment: Of course!  The .uniq is definitely a better approach than my first comment.  I must have been in a bad brain space yesterday!

Comment: @JeffZivkovic did you notice my edit, and new idea?

Comment: Oh Wow. @LesNightingill.  That is a really cool approach.  And I learned a new Rails concept from trying it out.  That's my favorite thing about StackOverflow answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is something better left for the database as iterating all the "Users" will become increasingly more inefficient as more "Users" are added .

Since your description is *"invitations where the inviter_id and the invitee_id matches any other invitation"* I am going to focus on that rather than the obfuscation into users.

You can obtain this information using the following query: [Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wpLCtApLpQgNoZrAnxUYKq/0)

```
SELECT 
invitations.* 
FROM 
invitations
WHERE 
    (invitations.inviter_id,invitations.invitee_id) IN (
      SELECT 
        invitations.inviter_id,
        invitations.invitee_id
      FROM 
        invitations
      GROUP BY 
        invitations.inviter_id,
        invitations.invitee_id
      HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1 
      )
```

We can rewrite this in a more *Railsy* fashion as follows:

```
invites_tbl = Invitation.arel_table
duplicate_invites = Invitation.where(
  Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new([invites_tbl[:inviter_id],invites_tbl[:invitee_id]]).in(
    Invitation
      .select(:inviter_id,:invitee_id)
      .group(:inviter_id,:invitee_id)
      .having(Arel.star.count.gt(1))
      .arel
  )
)
```

This will return all the `Invitiation` objects where there are other Invitations with the same `inviter_id` and `invitee_id`.

You could then group this further as needed e.g.

```
duplicate_invites.group_by {|i| [i.inviter_id, i.invitee_id]}
```